# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to\ 1}\frac{x+x^2+\cdots+x^n-n}{x-1}$ without L'Hospital's rule

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation, limits-without-lhopital

I used substitution $$t=x-1, x=t+1,x\rightarrow1\Rightarrow t\rightarrow 0$$

Now the expression is
$$\lim_{t\to\ 0}\frac{t+1+(t+1)^2+\cdots+(t+1)^n-n}{t}$$

Can we use the sum of geometric sequence or squeeze theorem?

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/451799/73025

Comment: See in particular [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/451802/73025) to avoid l'Hospital.

Comment: How about long division?

Comment: Why not just use l'Hopital's theorem?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: the numerator can be written:

$$(x-1)+(x^2-1) +\cdots + (x^n-1)$$